# trusting RMSE or trusting visualized result?

Tags: machine-learning, python, predictive-modeling

As has been shared everywhere, to see the performance of the model, it is essential to check one of the things such as `RMSE`, `MAE`, `score or R2`, etc. I totally agree. What should be done when the `RMSE` is relatively low but the plots show a kinda inconsistency in the result. The plot below is the result of a model with `RMSE eqauls to 0.01`.
[image]

I can not say that the predicted values and actual values are closed to each other because of having a small amount `RMSE`. What about you? Do you think they are closed?

Comment: Note that if you multiplied the dataset values by 100, your RMSE would go up too. The number on it's own can't tell you much about how good your model is, it can only be used to compare model accuracies in relative terms.

Comment: I'm not very suprised that the RMSE is very low, the model gets the shape of the curve very close to the actual values. It's only the amplitude which is predicted a bit too low. If you want to evaluate how close the two curves are, you could use a specific similarity measure.

Comment: @Erwan thanks for the comment. Can you share a bit more on the `Similarity measure`. Since I have not been familiar with the topic. Also, if you have any suggestions, I will appreciate them.

Comment: @Erwan Also I have to add this point that my case is `Supervised learning`

Comment: @john22 there are some similarity or distance measures which can be used to compare two sequences of points. In this case you would compare the predicted values against the true values, this might give you a more accurate way to evaluate the predictions. I don't know which measure is suitable for your case: cosine is a common one, but there are many others, including more advanced ones like [DTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping)